# How can i get the picture filename from a google drive url?

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a lot of picture links in my Google Sheet:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BDj24_6uz-ZQlGWLy0o1_DES6tJI3NMu/view?usp=sharing

I want to get the filename behind the link. When i open the link and save the image the image filename is: "FILENAME.jpg" or something similar

I want to get this information in Sheets.

How can i do that?

Comment: In your question, you say `I want to get this information in excel`. But in your tags, `google-sheets` is included while `excel` is not used. So I cannot understand about your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: If it is a solution based on a google sheet it´s fine for me. Also fine it is with excel.

My goal is, to get the filename... I´m not the owner of this file ...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to confirm whether my understanding of your question is correct. You have several links like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=sharing`. All links are publicly shared. You want to retrieve the filename from the link. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, I think that Google Apps Script might be suitable for your situation. How about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An Apps Script Solution

<sup>Thanks to @Tanaike for obtaining clarifications in the comments.</sup>

First enter your links in the format shown below in a Google Sheet.

[image]

The name of the titles is not important, but this particular script starts getting names from the 2nd row.

If you don't know how to create a script, there are [tutorials here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials) offered by Google. You should create the script from the same Sheet. That is, from the menu in the Sheet:

[image]

In the script editor, copy and paste the following code:

```js
function getNames() {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var height = activeRange.getHeight();
  var links = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange("A2:A" + height)
    .getValues();

  var nameValues = [];

  links.forEach((row) => {
    try {
      var link = row[0];
      var fileID = getIdFromLink(link);
      var name = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getName();
      nameValues.push([name]);
    } catch (e) {
      nameValues.push(["NO NAME FOUND"]);
    }
  });

  var nameRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2:B" + height);
  nameRange.setValues(nameValues);
}

function getIdFromLink(link) {
  var regex = new RegExp(
    /(?<=https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/file\/d\/)(.+)(?=\/)/
  );
  return regex.exec(link)[0];
}
```

Run the `getNames` function. The first time it will ask you to grant some permissions, grant them. Then it should fill in the files names.

[image]

#### References

- [Apps Script Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Spreadsheet service in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)
- [Drive service in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)